# JSP - Domain URL

Tags: jsp, url, dns, href, html

I would like to place a RETURN TO HOME link on all of my JSP pages, and since I am working in a DEV and PROD environments, I am wondering if there is a quick command, or variable I can place in an HREF that would take me to the Base Domain on either server.

```
<a href="${someMagicJSPFairyDust.requestYaddaYadda}">Return to Home</a>
```

that variable would take me to the home page no matter what server I'm on, whether it be:

```
http://development.domain.com
```

or

```
http://production.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`request#getContextPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath%28%29),

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.jsp">Return to Home</a>
```

will work independent of the domain names